# ImportError: DLL load failed with downloaded PYQT4. 64bit python2.7

Tags: python, django, dll

I am going to run a GUI program with main.py
After I run the main.py with using `cmd`, it shows the  result.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "Main.py", line 1, in <module>
        from MainGlobalVar import *
      File "C:\G02FYP\MainGlobalVar.py", line 4, in <module
        from NetworkConsole import *
      File "C:\G02FYP\NetworkConsole.py", line 1, in <modul
        from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have double-checked that  my version is 64 and I have re-installed the PYQT4
with using 64bits and python 2.7.9

Moreover,if I type python in cmd, it shows:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win
32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

What should i do for this importerror.